# 2 lists, if element x of list 1 has class y, add class to x element 2nd list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I'm in front of a puzzle. I can not split my problem into javascript / jQuery and I do not know how to do it.

I have two lists. Here is my first list.

```
<ul class="list1">
  <li class="with-iframe"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="with-iframe"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

My second list has the same number of elements but no class.

```
<ul class="list2">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I would like that if a `<li>` in my first list has an "with-iframe" class, the element in my second list (in the same position) also has the "with-iframe" class.

There will always be the same number of items in each list.

Is there a solution to support my problem?

Thank you for your help and explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply loop trough the elements of the first list and when you find an element with the class `with-iframe` add the same class to the item of the second list in that position.

So:

- Iterate on elements using `$(".list1 li").each(...)`
- Check class value of current item `if($(li).hasClass("with-iframe"))`
- Get the item of second list in same position `var li = $(".list2 li")[idx]`
- Finally add the same class to that element `$(li).addClass("with-iframe")`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".list1 li").each(function(idx, li) {
    if($(li).hasClass("with-iframe")){
      var li = $(".list2 li")[idx];
      $(li).addClass("with-iframe");
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list1">
  <li class="with-iframe"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="with-iframe"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list2">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I hope it helped you, bye.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as below:

```
$('.list1 li').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('with-iframe')) {
    $('.list2 li').eq(index).addClass('with-iframe');
  }
});
```

```js
$('.list1 li').each(function(index) {
 if ($(this).hasClass('with-iframe')) {
   $('.list2 li').eq(index).addClass('with-iframe');
  }
});
```

```css
.with-iframe {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list1">
  <li class="with-iframe">test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li class="with-iframe">test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

By pure JS.

```js
var l1 = document.querySelectorAll('ul.list1 li');
var l2 = document.querySelectorAll('ul.list2 li');

for (var i = 0; i<=l1.length-1;i++){
  l2[i].className=l1[i].className
}
```

```css
.with-iframe{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list1">
  <li class="with-iframe"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="with-iframe"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```js
$( ".list1 li.with-iframe" ).each( function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $( ".list2 li:nth-child("+(index+1)+")").addClass( "with-iframe" );
});
```

```css
.with-iframe
{
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First List

<ul class="list1">
  <li class="with-iframe"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="with-iframe"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

Second list

<ul class="list2">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```